# How to change height of default wordpress embed link "windows"

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

could anyone tell me if it's possible to make all these(in picture) wp-default links with class .wp-embed .post      same height so that it won't look horrible like in picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL8qY.png) I know that it is programmed so that the height addapts to text size inside it.

How do i do that, i can't find they way how to overwrite that with CSS. Is it only achievable by PHP / if so how - i can barely read PHP for now...

Comment: Please share some code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate questions here:

1. How do I change the css on a wordpress site?

The answer is that it will depend on the setup of your site.

-- You may have access to edit the css for the theme by going to Dashboard -> Appearance -> Editor and then finding the style.css

-- You may also have access to edit the css file through manually editting the file on the server.

-- if those first two options don't work, and you are able to add plugins, you can add a plugin to let you add css to the page.  Simple Custom Css is one such plugin.

2. How do I fix this particular css problem?

To answer this question I would need to see more of the css and html for this page

Comment: But these .wp-embed .links are the same in every theme right? Coz they are in WP by default, in page/post editor. I had this problem also in different themes, that i couldn't set the same hight for those link windows.  So why would you need to see more html & css ? Well, i can link it here, but which one i don't quite know.

Comment: No.  .wp-embed and .links are common to many themes, but they are far from ubiquitous.  And even if they were the same in every theme, the CSS would be different.

Comment: Ah ok, well i believe height is set by JS according to text (how much text ist there) so it i would have to delete that JS part and set the height somewhere in the CSS.. but well i really don"t know where and how to find it. https://catalog.martelbojnice.sk/aktualna-ponuka/

Comment: Ah... ok.  Now I see.  First of all, the problem is *not* with the height of the .wp-embed element.  That element is part of an iframe and it does indeed effect the height of the iframe.  Just as you suspected the height of the iframe is controlled by js and is based off the wp-embed.  But the display bug you are experiencing is because whatever browser is not correctly laying out.  What browser are you seeing that bug in?  It looks fine in Chrome and FF desktop.